# How to get a server-side ASP page to display a pop-up message in the client's browser?

Tags: asp.net

Ok. I have read dozens of articles on the fact that you can't use MessageBox.Show from a server-side ASP page. Makes sense. Those articles were advocating using "alert" to pop up a message (like a confirmation message, where the user has to click "OK" to acknowledge the message). Some postings talked about registering the code, but others didn't. I have tried all of the combinations I could find, but I still can't get my server-side ASP page to pop up a message in my client's browser!

Here's a snippet of the code in my code-behind page:

```
private void MessageBoxShow(Page page, string message)
{
    Literal ltr = new Literal();
    ltr.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'> alert('" + message + "') </script>";
    page.Controls.Add(ltr);
}
```

I have also tried this variation:

```
protected void MyTrace(string msg)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + msg + "')</script>");
}
```

Both of these work as expected if I'm going to localhost, but when I put my code on the server (under IIS 7.5) the messages never appear.

Can someone please give me a simple (but complete) answer that works? Thanks.

Comment: Do you see errors in your JavaScript console when running the code from the server?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to look for errors in the JavaScript console. How do I turn it on?

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser to access the JavaScript console.  In FireFox, the F12 shortcut only works if FireBug is installed.  Otherwise, Ctrl+Shift+K will bring up the native JavaScript console in FireFox.

Comment: Where are the `MessageBoxShow` or `MyTrace` methods called?

Comment: They're called in the code behind. But the problem has been solved. (See answer below.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their input. Turns out that most of the ideas were workable. My problem was in not realizing that the alert box didn't pop up until after the method was finished (makes sense in hindsight). I ended up using the simplest of the ideas, viz.,

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('" + msg + "')</script>");
```

Comment: Just to be clear... you had your debugger running on the server??

Comment: No, but now that you mention it, I wish I knew how to run the debugger on the server!

Answer (score 10):

I find alert boxes to be annoying.  Just create your own with HTML:

```
<div runat="server" id="AlertBox" class="alertBox" Visible="false">
    <div runat="server" id="AlertBoxMessage"></div>
    <button onclick="closeAlert.call(this, event)">Ok</button>
</div>
```

Show it in code:

```
private void MessageBoxShow(string message)
{
    this.AlertBoxMessage.InnerText = message;
    this.AlertBox.Visible = true;
}
```

Add some CSS to style it as a popup and some JavaScript to close it when "Ok" is clicked.  Here is a completed demo:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Demo.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demo" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Message Box Demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .alertBox
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 50%;
                width: 500px;
                margin-left: -250px;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 4px 8px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function closeAlert(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.parentNode.style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <div>
                [Regular page content here]
            </div>
            <div runat="server" id="AlertBox" class="alertBox" Visible="false">
                <div runat="server" id="AlertBoxMessage"></div>
                <button onclick="closeAlert.call(this, event)">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class MessageBoxDemo : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxShow("Welcome to my website!");
    }

    private void MessageBoxShow(string message)
    {
        this.AlertBoxMessage.InnerText = message;
        this.AlertBox.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work as-is. For example, I get a compile error on the closeAlert function (something about the parentNode not being legit). (I'm not much of a JavaScript person.)

Comment: @BarryDysert - You shouldn't be compiling the JavaScript.  I've updated my answer with a complete, tested page.

Comment: Thanks, gilly3, that makes a world of difference :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's working locally, but not on the server there are a few things to check.  Such as:

1. Is your browser caching the page?  Do a hard refresh (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) on the page and try again.
2. Are you sure the code is deployed?  Seems like a silly thing, but we have to ask.  Along with this is a follow up: Are you sure the code is deployed to the correct location?
3. Are you getting in javascript errors?

Comment: I've done ctrl+F5, but that doesn't help. Yes, I am sure the code is deployed correctly. (The application uses form validation, and the logon form is coming up. It's after I get past that that I'm trying to display a "message box".)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to register a startup script. See this MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Comment: That has the potential of being helpful. The Page_Load script, though, apparently supersedes the Page_Load C# method in my code-behind page. This is no good because I perform some important stuff in my Page_Load method. Can you nudge me along at getting this concept to work?

Comment: From MSDN: "The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised." I don't want it to execute immediately. I want my script only to execute when I tell it to. How do I workaround this?

Comment: Would need to see a little more of your code to provide any real help.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer use

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(String), "myScript", "alert('" & s.Replace("'", "'+String.fromCharCode(39)+'") & "')", True)
```